# How can I print infix from tree?

Tags: java, tree, postfix-mta, infix-notation

I want print my tree to infix.
Where is my problem? plz help me.[enter image description here][1]
thank you.
Other expressions are perfectly implemented in the Class.

```
public class SyntaxTree extends LinkedBinaryTree<String> {
public static SyntaxTree buildSyntaxTree(String[] expr) {
    Stack<SyntaxTree> stack = new Stack<>();

    for(int i =0; i < expr.length; i++) {
        if (expr[i].equals("+") || expr[i].equals("-") || expr[i].equals("*") || expr[i].equals("/")) {
            SyntaxTree subtree = new SyntaxTree();
            subtree.addRoot(expr[i]);

            SyntaxTree righttree = stack.pop();
            SyntaxTree lefttree = stack.pop();

            subtree.attach(subtree.root(), lefttree, righttree);
            stack.push(subtree);
        }
        else {
            SyntaxTree subtree = new SyntaxTree();
            subtree.addRoot(expr[i]);
            stack.push(subtree);
        }
    }
    SyntaxTree res = stack.pop();
    return res;
}



        public String parenthesize() {
        String ret = "";
        List<Node<String>> ls = inOrder();
        for (Node<String> node : ls) {
            if (isLeftChild(node)) ret += "(";

            String e = node.getElement();
            if (e.equals("+") ||e.equals("-") || e.equals("/") || e.equals("*")) {
                if (node.getLeft() != null) {
                    String l = node.getLeft().getElement();
                    if (!l.equals("+") && !l.equals("-") && !l.equals("/") && !l.equals("*")) {
                        ret += l;
                    }
                }
                ret += " " + e + " ";

                if (node.getRight() != null) {
                    String r = node.getRight().getElement();
                    if (!r.equals("+") && !r.equals("-") && !r.equals("/") && !r.equals("*")) {
                        ret += r;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isRightChild(node)) ret += ")";

        }
        return ret;
```

---

Expected :((1 + 2) * (3 + ((4 / 2) * 5)))
Actual   :((1 + 2) * (3 + )((4 / 2) * 5))

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is first time to use stack overflow, so I didn't know about that.

Comment: Why are you making a list?

Comment: I updated that. Other expressions are perfectly implemented in other Class.

Comment: input was String type(postfix)

Comment: It Seems to me that it would be much easier to build the expression string directly from the tree instead of the infix list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public String parenthesize(Node<String> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }
    String e = node.getElement();
    if (e.equals("+") ||e.equals("-") || e.equals("/") || e.equals("*")) {
        return "(" + parenthesize(node.getLeftChild())
                + e + parenthesize(node.getRightChild()) + ")";
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I will try!